# TCP Retransmission (TCP Port numbers reused) issues

Tags: networking, http, tcp, wireshark

I developed a web server and this is running on GKE.

Whenever I send any request to this server from my local pc, it occurs TCP retransmission.

Following is captured packets with Wireshark. The red boxes are client address, and the blue boxes are server address.

[image]

I found some features about this:

- If my server is running on my local pc, so the networking is localhost, everything is ok.
- TCP retransmission is occurred in very short time even though RTO of my pc is 1000ms as default.
- I sent requests from chrome browser, [talend api tester](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/talend-api-tester-free-ed/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm), and my Go program. Both chrome browser and Go program made TCP retransmissions while api tester doesn't.
- I found no duplicated port numbers before the image, but it says `TCP Port numbers reused`.

I am wondering why TCP retransmissions occur.

Comment: These might give you a hint on what's going on: [What does TCP DUP ACK mean?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38471/what-does-tcp-dup-ack-mean) in Network Engineering SE, [TCP Ports reused](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/26247/tcp-port-numbers-reused/) and [Is it a bad thing to see many [TCP Port numbers reused?](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/17955/is-it-a-bad-thing-to-see-many-tcp-port-numbers-reused/) in Wireshark community.